# Can I write PHP code across multiple lines per statement?

Tags: php, newline, structure

Is it okay to write code like this, with statements spanning across multiple lines?

```
$db_selected = 
mysql_select_db(
    'my_dbase', 
    mysql_connect(
        'localhost', 
        'mysql_user', 
        'mysql_password'
    )
);
```

In HTML, new lines are ignored, but in PHP I sometimes get errors. I'm not too familiar with PHP, but thought this should be just fine, no?

Answer (score 12):

No, but not for why you think. The whitespace is fine, but there is an issue with that code:

```
mysql_select_db(
    'my_dbase', 
    // don't call mysql_connect here!!!
    mysql_connect( 
        'localhost', 
        'mysql_user', 
        'mysql_password'
    )
);
```

MySQL connect will return FALSE on error. This means that you'll not be able to handle the `mysql_error()` there *AND* it will cause an error in `mysql_select_db`.

You're better off:

```
$conn = mysql_connect( 
        'localhost', 
        'mysql_user', 
        'mysql_password'
) or die( mysql_error() );

mysql_select_db(
    'my_dbase', 
    $conn // optional parameter, but useful nonetheless.
);
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm gonna answer my own question: Simply tried this and on my LAMP server, the originally posted code snippet works just fine (php 5).

**So yes, you can separate statements including those with operators into multiple lines.**

And the answer with the string concatenation - yes there are myriad answers on this forum already about that but I was asking about statements, not strings, which I could not find answered elsewhere.

Thanks everyone! Especially Geroge Cummins.

Comment: If George Cummins's answer is correct, then you (tim) should select the check mark next to it.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but for certain things, such as text I do something like ...

```
$someText = " blah blah blah ".
"some more blah blah blah";
```

Hope this helps

UPDATE 2022 haha

I know this is super old, but another way would be using EOF

```
$str = <<<EOF

   You can put whatever <p>text</p>. <b>you want to put</b> 
in here, for as
many lines as you want ()I)(#*$)#*($)#

EOF;
```

Comment: I find that it is clearer if the concatenation operator (".") is placed on the second line, directly beneath the assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace is generally ignored, so you can insert line breaks as needed. However, you need to end each statement with a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's okay, as long as there are no new lines after operators, such as `=`, `in`, `==`, etc...

Comment: Adding reference links and additional info: In general, yes. However, subsequent lines need to be indented by 4 characters, and `=` sign should go at the beginning of a new line, not at the end of the previous line. https://pear.php.net/manual/en/rfc.cs-enhancements.splitlongassignments.php Conditional operators are preferred at the beginning of next line, rather than at the end of the previous line, but it's unclear if that is a requirement, or simply a coding preference for the language: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/rfc.cs-enhancements.splitlongstatements.php

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer is correct. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/15805533/2943403