# Why PHP doesn't throw an error on missing semicolon?

Tags: php

The code below works perfectly in PHP. Can anyone explain to me how this code works? In the below code, I have declared `$caregory_id` without a semicolon and any value assignment. Then also this code works perfectly without any error and `var_dump($category_id)` returns me a `null` value.

How does PHP execute this code without a semicolon?

```
<?php
    $category_id= //No semicolon
    var_dump($category_id); //returns NULL
?>
```

Comment: Newline is not a statement terminator. What you have there is equivalent to `$foo = bar($foo);`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works because PHP treats your code like this:

```
$category_id = var_dump($category_id);
```

The return value of `var_dump()` gets assigned to `$category_id`. Undefined variables in PHP are implicitly set to `null`, which is what you see in the output of `var_dump()`. However, you would also get a notice about `$category_id` not being defined; if you don't see it, you should use this code in your script:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

These settings are also recommended during development as they can catch issues that would otherwise have gone unnoticed on a production machine.

Comment: Yeah, when you run this code through the parser, it will throw a notice: `Notice: Undefined variable: category_id in /var/www/yourscript.php : eval()'d code on line 2`

Comment: Thanks for detail description. i understand what happen.